# Converting simple nested select query to Laravel's Eloquent query

Tags: php, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-5.7

i am having this query with me which needs to be written in the eloquent form on internet not able to find exact solution for my problem.

```
SELECT 
    query_id, t1.time, result, platform_id
FROM
   query_logs t1
WHERE
    t1.time = (SELECT 
            MAX(time)
        FROM
            query_logs t2
        WHERE
            t1.query_id = t2.query_id);
```

i tried writing it as below i used query_Logs as model to my controller:

```
$bmdata = Query_Logs::select('query_id', 'time','result','platform_id')
              ->where('time', function($q){
              $q->from('query_logs')
               ->selectRaw('max(time)')
               ->where('query_id', '=', 'query_id')
           })
           ->get();
```

Can you guys help me with the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$bmdata = Query_Logs::select('query_id', 'time', 'result', 'platform_id')
    ->where('time', function($q) {
        $q->from('query_logs as t2')
            ->selectRaw('max(time)')
            ->whereColumn('t2.query_id', '=', 'query_logs.query_id');
   })->get();
```